# Is it best practice to place all android tests (units / integrations / UI tests) into a single test project?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I've got my main application project, and then a second project for my tests. Is it good practice to store all types of tests in that test project, or should some reside in the main application project?

Should I keep POJO JUnits (ones that test non-android derived classes) in my main project, or group them all together? I can't see anything on the Google documentation that advises where to locate tests.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than creating two projects, its very good practice to create a second 'source' folder in the original android (or java) project and put your tests in that.  When you export as an app, you can exclude that source folder from the compiled application.

[image: Adding another source folder]

[image: Excluding files from the export]

Answer (score 1):

[The Android test documetation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html#TestProjects) says

> ... the best approach is to add the test project so that its root directory `tests/` is at the same level as the `src/` directory of the main application's project.

There is even an illustration of the directory structure in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html#TestProjects).

Jarl